# character replace using in perl

Tags: perl, sed

Hi am trying to remove ':' from variable `s`.

I did following procedure but it is not working

```
$s="2:2:2:2:2";
$v=$(sed 's/://g' <<< $s);
print $v;
```

any solution 
thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First: what is `$s`?

If it should contain a string, you have to add quotes.

Next: `$(...)` is shell programming, not perl.

Then there's no need to run a shell script to replace characters. You can do this within perl.

```
$s = "2:2:2:2:2";
$s =~ s/://g;
print $s;
```

If you really, for whatever reason, want to use *sed* for this, and you want to write a perl script that does it, you would have to write it like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$s="2:2:2:2:2";
$v=`sed 's/://g' <<< $s`;
print $v;
```

Comment: $s string .. i forgot to keep quotes